# Performance Issue loading images thumbnails in RecyclerView

Tags: android, image, performance, android-bitmap

I'm developing a File Manager, when I detect images in the current directory,I would like to show a thumbnail to the user. I can do that, the only problem is that when there are images in the directory all UI becomes slow and laggy. I would like to ask some ways to improve performance. Here's the pieces of code:

Here I check if the file is an image:

```
fileName = file.getName();
fileName = fileName.substring(fileName.lastIndexOf('.') + 1);
if(fileName.equals("jpg"))
         dir.add(new Item(ff.getName(), ff.length() + " Byte", date_modify, ff.getAbsolutePath(), "image_icon"));
```

Here is the FileAdapter code to set the imageView of the recycler view row:

```
if(item.getImage().equals("image_icon")){
Bitmap ThumbImage = ThumbnailUtils.extractThumbnail(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(item.getPath()),
                        100, 100);
holder.icon.setImageBitmap(ThumbImage);
 }
```

Tell me if more code is needed.

Comment: use [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide) to load images

Answer (score 0):

Add in dependencies

```
compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
```

And write in your adapter

```
Glide.with(mContext).load(imgUrl)
            .thumbnail(0.5f)
            .crossFade()
            .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
            .into(holder.icon);
```

Comment: Thanks, now it's not laggy, but it loads images slowly. Are there ways to make it faster?